# how to select specific number of column for specific number of ID?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi I have the following table

```
table_A

ID    NAME   PRICE   DATE
123   JOHN   22      1/1/2010
234   KING   50      5/10/2009
345   JACK   400     30/11/210
```

Expected out put:

I want to pick first column for fist ID and second column for second ID and third column for third ID.

```
ID    VALUES
123   JOHN
234   50
345   30/11/2010
```

My query:

```
select ID, NAME
from table_A
where ID = 123

union all

select ID, PRICE
from table_A
where ID = 234

union all

select ID, DATE
from table_A
where ID = 345;
```

Two reason that my query is not correct:
1) it don't union different data types
2) its difficult to type all ID and so, many unions

Need better query so, it automatically pick first loan for first column and second loan for second column...

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: How about converting each column to a string, union should work then

Comment: cannt we do something like using Loop.

Comment: You could create a cursor. But try my example below. It should be working

Comment: Your request doesn't make sense. "Using loop" means you want to do something in a procedure or function; no mention of that in your question. In SQL, you show you want a column "values" in a result table, but you DON'T want all the values cast to strings. That is not possible. All values in a column must have the same data type. You can't have a string, a date and a number in the same column. You can have their string representation, but you said you don't want that. SO - back to the drawing board. What are you really trying to do? What you have shown so far is how you tried it, not what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work but you do have to convert all your data to the same format:

```
with test_data(ID1,    NAME1,   PRICE,   DATE1)
as (
select 123,   'JOHN',   22,     '1/1/2010'  from dual union all
select 234,   'KING',   50,     '5/10/2009' from dual union all
select 345,   'JACK',   400,    '30/11/210' from dual
)

select ID1, DATA
FROM
(
  select ID1, DATA, COL,
  row_number() over (partition by ID1 order by id1) RN,
  dense_rank() over (order by id1) DR
  from (
    select 
      cast(ID1 as varchar(10)) ID1, 
      cast(NAME1 as varchar(10)) NAME1, 
      cast(PRICE as varchar(10)) PRICE,
      cast(DATE1 as varchar(10)) DATE1
    FROM test_data
  ) 
  unpivot
  (
   DATA for COL in (NAME1, PRICE, DATE1) 
  )
)
where DR = RN


ID1        DATA     
---------- ----------
123        JOHN       
234        50         
345        30/11/210
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
     cast(ID as varchar(10)), 
     cast(NAME as varchar(10))
from table_A
where ID = 123

union all

select 
     cast(ID as varchar(10)),
     cast(PRICE as varchar(10))
from table_A
where ID = 234

union all

select 
     cast(ID as varchar(10)),
     cast(DATE as varchar(10))
from table_A
where ID = 345;
```

Comment: I created that table for example in which I just have 3 ID and 3 columns but in real life 100's of columns and 100's of ID. its difficult to create such big code.